# What happened with Akane in the manga? Did something like this happen in the novel?

Tags: kampfer

I've just read the tenth chapter of manga, Kämpfer (got it before I got 9 and 8).
I'm a bit confused by the ending there and wikipedia didn't help much there.

I'm putting up spoiler tags as the important parts of the question below are directly related to the endings of the manga / novel:

Manga:

> After destroying the statue, Akane suddenly disappeared. Why did that happen (I found the bit explanation before quite confusing but it sounded so as if Akane was created by the moderator?)?

Novels:

> Additionally this gets to the second part of my question. Is there something similar there in the novels? As from what I remember, he got together with Akane there. So is it different there for her to whatever happens to her in the manga?

Comment: I can't make tags. The Manga is "Kämpfer". But you are right though. I forgot to put it into the question after not being able to set it in tag

Comment: @tyhja tnx for teh edit!

Comment: the [tag:retag] tag is there if the tag you're looking to add does not exist and you don't have the rep to create it.

Comment: ah tnx looked for something like that but didnt see it^^